# How to return array as multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I i'm developing php application. I have used Google Chart API for display charts.
I have select and returned necessary data for chart.
I got following array as my output.

```
 print_r($output);

    //Out put

    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => April
            [sec_id] => 2
            [sec_name] => Commerce
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => June
            [sec_id] => 2
            [sec_name] => Commerce
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => July
            [sec_id] => 2
            [sec_name] => Commerce
            [count] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => August
            [sec_id] => 4
            [sec_name] => Science
            [count] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => August
            [sec_id] => 3
            [sec_name] => Maths
            [count] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [month] => August
            [sec_id] => 1
            [sec_name] => Art
            [count] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [month] => August
            [sec_id] => 2
            [sec_name] => Commerce
            [count] => 2
        )

)


    print_r(json_encode($output)); // return above array as output
```

I request above data using ajax ( data type is JSON)
**I want to return data as bellow** to generate google chart.

```
[
['Month', 'Art', 'Commerce', 'Maths', 'Sience'],
['April',  '', 2, '', ''],
['June',  '', 3, '', ''],
['July',  '', 1, '', ''],
['August',  2, 2, 3, 3]
 ]
```

**I tried this this code**

```
$output = array();
$output[0] = array('Month', 'Art', 'Commerce', 'Maths', 'Science');

foreach($records as $key=> $record){
    $art =''; $commerce =''; $maths=''; $science='';
    if($record['sec_id'] == 1){
        $art = $record['count'];
    }else if($record['sec_id'] == 2){
        $commerce = $record['count'];
    }else if($record['sec_id'] == 3){
        $maths = $record['count'];
    }else if($record['sec_id'] == 4){
        $science = $record['count'];
    }

    $output[++$key] = array(0 => $record['month'], 1 => $art, 2 => $commerce, 3 => $maths, 4 => $science);
}

function super_unique($array){
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    if ( is_array($value)){
      $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
    }
  }
    return $result;
}


$output = super_unique($output);
```

**Out put was**

```
[["Month","Art","Commerce","Maths","Science"],["April","","1"],["June","","3"],["July","","1"],{"0":"August","1":"","4":"3"},{"0":"August","1":"","3":"2"},["August","2",""],["August","","2"]]
```

Comment: Isn't the output same? It seems the output you want is on different lines but essentially the same

Comment: Note: line breaks are not valid in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to loop through and reorganize, particularly since your `sec_id`s match up nicely with the array indices.

#### Example:

```
$temp = array();
$output = array(
    array('Month', 'Art', 'Commerce', 'Maths', 'Science')
);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $month  = $record["month"];
    $sec_id = $record["sec_id"];
    $count  = $record["count"];

    if (!isset($temp[$month])) {
        $temp[$month] = array_fill(0, 5, '');
    }

    $temp[$month][0]        = $month;
    $temp[$month][$sec_id] += $count;
}

$output = array_merge($output, array_values($temp));

echo json_encode($output);
```

---

#### Output:

```
[["Month","Art","Commerce","Maths","Science"],["April","",2,"",""],["June","",3,"",""],["July","",1,"",""],["August",2,2,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rethink your algorithm. As you go through each element in records, we need to ask two things: what data are we pulling out and what do we want to do with it?

The first question is simple: we're just pulling out the value 'count'.

The second question is going to determine our algorithm. What we want to do is take that 'count' value, and stick it a particular spot in our ourpur array.

Looking at the output array as a table, we can see that the desired position of 'count' is determined by the 'month' field (which determines the row) and by the 'sec_id'/'sec_name' fields (which determine the column). So what you want your loop to look like is this...

```
foreach($records as $record)
 {
  $output[$record['month']][$record['sec_id']] = $record['count']
 }
```

The first caveat to this is that for each unique month, you do still need to create and initialize the sub-array, and you must do it only once. So, the loop becomes.

```
foreach($records as $record)
 {
  if(!is_array($output[$record['month']]))
    $output[$record['month']] = array(0 => $record['month'], 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', 4 => '');

  $output[$record['month']][$record['sec_id']] = $record['count']
 }
```

Finally, we used the actual month name as the keys in the top-level array. To comply with the numeric-only keys specified in your desired output, we can ditch those keys with the following piece of code.

```
$output = array_values($output)
```

If I'm right in thinking you were trying to use super_unique() to combine rows with the same month, that's not what it was doing at all. Firstly, array_unique() doesn't combine rows, it eliminates duplicates. Since you were comparing serialized rows, rather than just looking at the month field, none of your rows were duplicates, so that function was doing nothing. Furthermore, since several of your array fields were set to '', the serialize/unserialize process was actually causing those fields to get dropped, which is why you were ending up with sub-arrays of less than five elements, and with associative keys.